# Syntax Highlighter WordPress Plugins for Swift and Objective-C

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I'm working on my blog and I want to add blogs of both objective-C. Similar to this:

[image]

Were you can switch between Objective-C and Swift.

Any of you knows a plugin can do this?

I'll really appreciate you help.